# Is it possible to change namespaces's names of an object returned through a Remoting?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a 3 tier application. 1 and 2 tier communicate with each other through a remoting.

Further, lets say we have a one common assembly, referenced by 1 and 2 tier.
2 tier returns the class of the that common assembly to the 1 tier.

So in this scenerio both layers (1 and 2) have to has referenced the common assembly..

The question (maybe stupid) is ...
  Is it possible to change on the fly returned type(namespace) (from 2 to 1 layer) so that 
all classes would reference the main namespace.

Generally the idea is to pack all classes to only one assembly (in the 1 layer) that I could have only one executable... I just want to get rid of external assemblies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use .Net Remoting you need to reference a common assembly.

You cannont change the namespace of an object after it is created. You could map the object to a new object with the same structure but a different namespace. But this does not reduce your need to reference the dll with the original object.

If possible you should start to migrate away from Remoting and over to WCF.

Comment: I was just asking this, because If i wanted to ilmerge all client's files to one executable then, returned object will be obviously in that exe. And Now I am just thinking if anything I can do with that ...